# Plug, use option passed at init with Plug.Router syntax

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using Plug and I would like to understand.

My code looks like:

```erlang
defmodule Numerino.Plug do
  use Plug.Router
  use Plug.Debugger

  plug :put_resp_content_type, "application/json"
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  def init options do
    IO.inspect options
    options
  end

  get "/" do
    conn
    |> IO.inspect
    |> send_resp(201, "world")
  end

  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "Not found.")
  end

end
```

Inside the get I would need to use the `option` passed as argument.

How can I access the options keeping the same Plug.Router syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified why you want to do this, so I can only give a generic answer. If you have a specific use case then there may be a better solution.

---

You can do this by adding an additional plug to the router which stores the opts in the private storage of the conn:

```
plug :opts_to_private

defp opts_to_private(conn, opts) do
  put_private(conn, :my_app_opts, opts)
end
```

This will then be accessible in your routes with `conn.private.my_app_opts`:

```
get "/" do
  conn.private.my_app_opts
  |> IO.inspect

  conn
  |> send_resp(201, "world")
end
```

The dispatch function is [defoverridable/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#defoverridable/1) so you can also do the same thing by overriding the function:

```
defp dispatch(conn, opts) do
  conn = put_private(conn, :my_app_opts, opts)
  super(conn, opts)
end
```

However I find defining a new function such as `opts_to_private` cleaner.

Comment: I found both solution pretty bad... Thank you anyway :)

Comment: This is no longer working in current Plug. I get `[]` as opts in `opts_to_private` (in init I get proper opts).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to override the call callback:

```
  def call(conn, opts) do
    put_private(conn, :opts, opts)
    |> super(opts)
  end
```

Comment: This is the better answer!